# UML Class Diagram: How do I correctly represent a vector of derived classes using their base class?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have an application that consists of a server that can have multiple clients of two types, **user clients**, and **device clients**. To do this, I have a vector of the client base class where I will add the new clients as they connect to the server. This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
class Client
{
protected:
    int m_port;
    Client(int port): m_port{port}{}
public:
    virtual ~Client(){}
}

class User: public Client
{
public:
    User(int port): Client{port}{}
    virtual ~User(){}
}

class Device: public Client
{
public:
    User(int port): Client{port}{}
    virtual ~Device(){}
}

class Server
{
public:
    Server(int port): m_port{port}{}

    ~Server()
    {
       for (std::vector<Client*>::iterator it = m_clients.begin();
            it != m_clients.end();
            it++){
           free(m_clients.pop_back());
           }
    }

    void run()
    {
        if(m_port == 1){
            m_clients.pushback(new User(port));
        }else{
            m_clients.pushback(new Device(port));
        }
    }
private:
    int m_port;
    std::vector<Client*> m_clients;
}
```

And I have the following UML representation:

[image]

My doubt here is if this diagram represents the correct intent. Maybe I'm not that experienced with UML and this is enough, but I think this diagram doesn't clearly depict the fact that the vector in the server will contain **User**(s) and **Device**(s) and not **Client**(s). I don't know if I need to put an extra stereotype label, an extra note, or an extra link or association like this:

[image]

So, **how would this c++ class relationship be correctly represented in UML?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this diagram doesn't clearly depict the fact that the vector in the server will contain User(s) and Device(s) and not Client(s). I don't know if I need to put an extra stereotype label, an extra note, or an extra link or association

you just have to say the class *Client* is *abstract* in your first diagram, you can show that  writting its name in italic in the diagram. Do not add associations as you did in the second diagram.

Warning `m_client` is private in *Server* but you used a + rather than a -

<s>You use a composition between *Server* and *Client*, are you sure this is is the case and then the clients disappear when the server disappears ? There is nothing in the C++ code doing that.</s> (see OP remark)

Having drawn `m_client` as an association it is not necessary to also show it as an attribute.

The clients do not know the server, this is more visible drawing the association non bidirectional (i.e. `Server -------> Client`).

The C++ definition uses a *vector* where the elements are ordered, you can indicate the property is ordered using `{ordered}`

Because of the C++ definition of *run* with `if(m_port == 1)` a server has client(s) or-exclusive device(s), you can indicate that through a constraint

`<<ctor>` and `<<vector>>` are not defined in the standard but I have nothing against their use.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just put the `<<ctor>>` and `<<vector>>` for this post and I don't have that in the complete (bigger) diagram. You are right, I didn't put that in this code example but yeah, all the clients will disappear when the server disappears. I'll modify the post to reflect that.

Comment: ok, so basically to answer the original question, I only need to indicate that **Client** is abstract, right? *(by the way, thanks for the additional comments for things not asked but that I needed to know)*

Comment: @m4l490n yes it is

Comment: @m4l490n yes, an abstract class cannot be instantiated, this is the case in the C++ code you give because the constructor is not public, so clients are in fact user(s) or device(s) supposing there are no other class inheriting *Client*